# jquery ajax response status in done

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX call;

```
return $.ajax({
  url: requestUrl
})
.done(function (response, status, xhrObject) {
    // Should I put some condition here to check if request is processed ?
  response.actual = {};
  resolve(response);
}).fail(function (xhrObject, status, error) {
  var errorObj = {};
  errorObj.status = status;
  reject(errorObj);
});
```

Now my question is for the "done" callback, do I need to add some check for the request status.
I am asking this as I have observed that sometimes control goes inside the "done" even while the request is in progress ?

Just to add, below is how the status/xhrObject look while this happens (i.e. when control goes inside done callback).

```
status = "success", xhrObject = Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "load"}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by saying 'control goes inside the "done" *even when the request is in progress*' ? (emphasis mine) - the request is receiving a response of '200 - success' - so I am not sure I understood that part correctly

Comment: I have added a breakpoint inside the done callback & it went there even while the server response was not yet received !